# Prevent an item from updating while approval workflow in process and once completed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a calendar list in SharePoint 2010 where I have a SharePoint designer workflow for approving vacation request. Approval workflow is working fine and there is also an event receiver when an item is deleted that sends email to requester and approver. I want to Prevent an item ( event) from updating while approval workflow in process and once completed. I want to see the below screenshot and show error msg to user that says which is highlighted in the edit form
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this. Add a Rule in the Form Open Event to check the Workflow Status.  If it is set to In Progress (2) then set the form (a New View) to ReadOnly View.  Here is a breakdown of the Values (Whatever you name the Workflow, becomes a Metadata Column in the list. That is what you check for)

Status  Value
Not Started 0
Failed on Start 1
In Progress 2
Error Occurred  3
Canceled    4
Completed   5
Failed on Start (retrying)  6
Error Occurred (retrying)   7
Canceled    15
Approved    16
Rejected    17